# Cast from a delegate to a func

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a project in school where my teacher is asking us to add a delegate to a List of Funcs.  The code I have below is having issues in the AddDel method. Intellisense is telling me that it can't convert from the Delegate into a Func but my teacher insists that it should totally do that without a problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    private delegate string MyDel(int iVal, double dVal, char cVal, string sVal);
    private List<Func<int, double, char, string, string>> _DList;
    public TestDelegate() { }       
    public void AddDel()
    {            
        //Creating a delegate
        MyDel myDel = new MyDel(MyFunction);
        _DList.Add(myDel); //Adding it to the TestDelegate
    }
    public void RunTests()
    {
        int idata = 1;
        double ddata = 5.1;
        char cdata = 'A';
        string sdata = "Method";
        foreach (Func<int, double, char, string, string> myDel in _DList)
            WriteLine(myDel(idata, ddata++, cdata++, sdata + idata++));
    }
    private static string MyFunction(int iVal, double dVal, char cVal, string sVal)
    {
        return $"{sVal}:\t{iVal} {dVal}{cVal}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't declare your own delegate here at all. There are no conversions between delegate types like this.

You want a `Func<int, double, char, string, string>`, so declare one:

```
Func<int, double, char, string, string> func = MyFunction;
_DList.Add(func);
```

Or more simply, just call Add:

```
_DList.Add(MyFunction);
```

If you really want to keep your current code, you can create a `Func<...>` that *wraps* your delegate:

```
MyDel myDel = new MyDel(MyFunction);
var func = new Func<int, double, char, string, string>(myDel);
_DList.Add(func); //Adding it to the TestDelegate
```

... but I don't actually see any benefit from that here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but for the sake of what my professor wants me to do for the project, is it even possible to cast a delegate to a Func?

Comment: @McKenzieWinward: No, it's not. See my final addition though - you can create a new delegate that wraps the old one. Note that the `Func<...>` **is** a delegate type... it's just not one you've declared.

Comment: I don't see the benefits either but your answer is exactly what I was looking for nonetheless.  In the rubric for the project he did say something about using a wrapper.  Thanks a ton!